# Android - Access MainActivity Instance

Tags: android, instance, main-activity

i have a public method in my MainActivity.java and want to call it from another Activity. Therefore i need the MainAcitivity Instance. How can i access it from another Acitivity.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't something that should normally be required, but if it is: you just have to pass the activity to the other. If the second activity is created by the main activity, most likely pass it in the extras bundle.

Comment: That's a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

You can get help about message passing between activities by [Broadcast Receivers](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments that "This isn't something that should normally be required", but still if you want this you can make that method static in MainActivity.java.

```
public static void someMethod()
{
}
```

and then in another activity, call this way:

```
MainActivity.someMethod();
```